# Where is crontab's time command documented?

Tags: crontab

I'm searching for the documentation of the `time` command that can be prepended to the script in crontab

```
* * * * * time somescript.sh
```

Comment: Where's the time output going?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/bin/time`. Not cron-specific, a general tool available on Unix-like systems.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/time/

Comment: Thanks @ckhan: I was confused by the built-in time command of my bash-shell which behaves different

Comment: Perhaps of interest is that although `time` has no special significance to the POSIX shell, to Bash it is a reserved word and an optional part of the syntax of pipelines.  That's more deeply integrated into Bash than a built-in command (which `time` is not).